# How to get all sub directories under a directory using uribuilder

Tags: c#, ftp, directory-listing

Trying to create an `UriBuilder` that will list all the subdirectories for later use.

I have tried the examples from Microsoft for this process and tried using the `directory.getdirectory` method without success.

```
String result = String.Empty;
Search searchResults = new Search();

try
{
    UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
    uriBuilder.Scheme = "ftp";
    uriBuilder.Host = "ftp.myfilepath.com/public/doc";
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.Uri);

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

    Console.WriteLine($"Directory List Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");

    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();

    if (result != null)
    {
        searchResults.Messages = result;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    searchResults.Messages = "File not found.";
}
```

I want it to list out the directories found under path given by the `UriBuilder`. The result always comes up empty and I don't understand why or what it is I am missing.

Comment: But it prints the directory contents to the console properly (using the statement on the line 12), it's just the `result` variable which is empty, am I right?

Comment: Is the result really empty? Don't you get any exceptions? You should. Also, I don't think it has anything to do with ASP.NET MVC or UriBuilder.

Comment: The response = null as well.

Comment: result = "" is what is gets in the debugger.

Comment: That's weird. I guess you're running a slightly different code or you're missing some parts here, because the code from your question contains 2 syntax errors and if those are fixed, it should throw an exception on the line 18 before it even assigned anything to the `result` variable. Try the code from my answer and ideally try it isolated (without any other code).

Comment: I pasted the exact code.  So I am not sure what the issue is.  By all accounts and testing it should work.

Comment: So for example on the line 18, you're using the variable `result`, which is not declared anywhere. That means, there's a syntax error (missing `var` keyword) or you didn't provide all code. If you're using a different code, there may be some other issue I'm not aware of and it's hard to help you if I don't know the full code.

Comment: the code is inside a try/catch block and the result is outside it.              String result = String.Empty;
            Search searchResults = new Search();

Comment: If you're hoping the ftp server will recursively list all sub dirs in response to your single command, you might be disappointed

Comment: Ok, that's not helpful.  Perhaps you can offer a solution.

Comment: OK, so you have more code than you shared with us, that may be the problem. Get the code from my answer, change the FTP server URL to `speedtest.tele2.net`, create a new console application and **put there only the code from my answer, not even single line more than that**. If it throws any exceptions, share them with us. If you're mixing the code with some other we don't know, we cannot help you, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

Disregarding few syntax errors (missing keyword `var` or type declaration on the lines 18 and 22), your code is working properly. The only problem is that you're calling `reader.ReadToEnd()` twice and moreover, the second call is just after you explicitly closed both the `ResponseStream` and `StreamReader`.

The first call is on the line 12 which prints the directory listing to the console:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

And the second call is on the line 18, where you're trying to get its return value into a variable `result`:

```
result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

But it's just after you closed both the `ResponseStream` and `StreamReader`:

```
reader.Close();
response.Close();
result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

So you even get an error message which is explaining what you're doing wrong:

> Cannot read from a closed TextReader.

It's an exception thrown on the line 18.

Even if you would move both calls to the `Close()` methods after the line 18, it won't work anyway, because the first call to the `reader.ReadToEnd()` method empties the reading buffer and disposes the `NetworkStream` object, so there would be the following exception thrown on the line 18:

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

### Solution

What you need to do is to call the method `reader.ReadToEnd()` just once, do it before you close both the `ResponseStream` and the `StreamReader` and store its return value in a variable. Then, you can do whatever you want with the result:

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
uriBuilder.Scheme = "ftp";
uriBuilder.Host = "ftp.myfilepath.com/public/doc";
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.Uri);

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine($"Directory List Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");

reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

### Working example

The following code has to be working if you do everything exactly as suggested:

1. create a new solution in Visual Studio containing a console application project, use the .NET Framework 4.7.2
2. put the following code into `Program.cs`:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Net;

   namespace FtpDirectoryListing
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
               uriBuilder.Scheme = "ftp";
               uriBuilder.Host = "speedtest.tele2.net";
               var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.Uri);

               request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

               var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

               var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
               var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
               var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

               Console.WriteLine(result);
               Console.WriteLine($"Directory List Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");

               reader.Close();
               response.Close();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run it
4. Share any potential errors it generates with us

Comment: It's working for me. You can try it with the public FTP server `speedtest.tele2.net`. It properly lists its content. If that will work for you also, maybe it's some issue with your FTP server.

Comment: Well, I tried this code and it came up with 8 errors.

Comment: I am beginning to think it might be a server issue.

Comment: Did you try it with the FTP server I suggested?

Comment: Not yet.  I will though.

Comment: I change result = response.StatusDescription and got 226 Directory send OK.

Comment: It isn't giving the directory list.

Comment: Then it's some other code or information you didn't share with us. If I put the code from my answer (and only that code, not single line more than that) into LINQPad 5 or into a console application (.NET Framework 4.7.2) in Visual Studio, in both it's working properly and in both it prints the directory listing to the console, if I'm using the FTP server `speedtest.tele2.net`. I'm afraid I cannot help you, my code is working properly in two independent environments.

Comment: Please, try to do what I suggest under the *Working example* section, **exactly**. **Don't add any other code!** And share the result with us.

Comment: Great, finally! Why did it have to take so long? That just means the issue is with the code you didn't share with us. Obviously, I cannot help you with the code I don't know. Since I fixed the code you posted in your question, I suggest you to accept my answer and if you have any other issue, create a new question, where you'll share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue.

Comment: I get blank otherwise the code runs fine without errors.  It takes so long because I am working remotely and having a thunderstorm...

Comment: What you get if you [run this](http://ferenczy.cz/temp/stackoverflow/FtpDirectoryListing.exe)? The solution is [here](http://ferenczy.cz/temp/stackoverflow/FtpDirectoryListing.zip).

Comment: This is a work machine and I am blocked from running your exe.

Comment: And the solution?

Comment: VS will not load the solution correctly.  It errors out  and will not load.  Working on it to see if I can get it to load.

Comment: Ok, I got it to load and run.  The console came up blank but without errors.

Comment: Then it's something with your machine or set up. Try to run it on another machine.

Comment: So was that the cause why it was failing for you? Is it working finally? That's weird, I didn't have to run it elevated.

Comment: Yes.  I know really weird.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you have solved the issue! I would appreciate if you could give my answer an up vote as a satisfaction, since it took me really a lot of time.

Comment: I did but it doesn't show because my reputation is too low.